# Why should I call wglCreateContext twice per context if I'm using C#, and once per context if using C++?

Tags: c#, opengl

I don't understand some of the pieces of the puzzle here. A C++ developer only has to call `wglCreateContext` once to setup a context (whether it be a dummy context, or their main context). A C# developer is recommended to call `wglCreateContext` **twice** to setup a context (and to ignore the result of the first call if it fails).

For example, here's an extract from [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/)'s source code:

```
Handle = new ContextHandle(Wgl.Imports.CreateContext(window.DeviceContext));
if (Handle == ContextHandle.Zero)
    Handle = new ContextHandle(Wgl.Imports.CreateContext(window.DeviceContext));
if (Handle == ContextHandle.Zero)
    throw new GraphicsContextException(
        String.Format("Context creation failed. Wgl.CreateContext() error: {0}.",
            Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
```

As I understand it, `opengl32.dll` seems to override some of the APIs that `gdi32.dll` exposes (such as `ChoosePixelFormat`), thus making it matter which order these DLLs get loaded. With C++, I *think* that means the order in which you link libraries is important. With C#, you don't link libraries, and `DllImport` does [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) and so I *think* calling the function twice somehow gets the ordering eventually right.

Can anyone confirm what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, one of the weird consequences of Microsoft's Installable Client Driver (ICD) / Mini Client Driver model for OpenGL. If you can manage to call a function from `opengl32.dll` that is not in `gdi32.dll` (there are a lot of them) you can get C# to import `opengl32.dll`'s symbol table over-top gdi32.

You could probably accomplish the same thing simply by calling `glGetError (...)` immediately before you begin the process of creating a context. Obviously it is an error to call `glGetError (...)` with no active context, but that is beside the point - you just need an API call that will get the ball rolling importing DLL symbols.

It is much easier in C/C++, because linkage to DLLs is resolved partially at build-time (DLL import order is established by library order in the linker switches). In C/C++, this issue is resolved simply by linking to gdi32.lib before opengl32.lib.

The idea is the same though, `ChoosePixelFormat (...)` has to be overridden by hardware vendor distributed OpenGL ICDs in order to match requested format parameters against a set of hardware accelerated pixel formats. If you use gdi32's version of `ChoosePixelFormat (...)` you will never get any hardware accelerated pixel formats, just the lousy software-based OpenGL 1.1 reference implementation that has been layered on top of GDI since Windows NT/95 OSR2. And obviously nobody wants that, because the reference implementation is not extendable, you are forever stuck with OpenGL 1.1 if you wind up with a GDI pixel format.

Comment: Excellent explanation! I just wonder one thing now, if I wrap OpenGL context creation into a small C DLL (exposing only `extern BOOL SetupWGL(HDC hdc);`, and call that from C#, is it guaranteed to resolve this issue? For instance, could there still be context creation errors due to linkage issues even when context creation is done in a C DLL (with the correct ordering of linked libraries) that is called from my C# process?

Comment: @Mr.Smith: That is an interesting idea, and that should work. I had to do something similar in MacOS X to write 64-bit software in C that uses OpenGL. The C interface (Carbon) to the window manager is only available in 32-bit form, so libraries like SDL2, GLFW3, etc. wind up having to be partially implemented in Objective C to offer 64-bit support on OS X. It is a little easier to mix and match Obj-C and C/C++ than it is to mix C# and C/C++, but a DLL written in C that does your context management is effectively the same thing (it _might_ be overkill in this situation though).